# "Sequence contains no match elements" - Intellisense Compile

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine, compilation, intellisense

I'm developing a game in Unity, everything is working and Visual Studio 2022 DOES COMPILE with zero errors. However, i'm trying to install a package with Nuget Package Manager but when I click to install Visual Studio shows in "List of Errors": "Sequence contains no match elements". This is an Intellisense error because it hides when I toggle "Compile + Intellisense" to "Compile only".

I've searched a lot and every solution to this error is related to Linq First(), Last() and Single(). I've already changed all to FirstOrDefault, i've even tried to comment ALL MY CODE and still not working, also tried to deactivate Intellisense and hide/ignore it's errors...

It is in portuguese, but it's the error decribed:
[Erros List Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5vb2.png)

As you can see, no information of file, stacktrace, line... Since it is not a running exception, but IntelliSense compile error, i have no idea what to do...

Game is in early development, so not much things going on... I'm suspecting one of the two packages I installed in unity: GithubForUnity and Photon Pun 2 Free

Comment: Intellisense errors tell you there's a suspected logic error in your code, not a syntax error. Don't worry about it if your code compiles and runs. Lots of devs turn off the intellisense errors. In this case it sounds like youve written a linq query that it knows will be empty or something like that

Comment: If you want help with the error you'll need to post the code, but often it's not a meaningful error.

Comment: I don't think this is a bug in your code. Instead of looking in the errors gui, look through the raw text outputs and see if the exact text is in there. I think some plug-in for your VS, or part of the background build routines or similar is encountering this exception; "sequence contains no elements" is a runtime one so some code must be running and throwing it. For that to occur when you're not performing a debug implies it's not your code. The errors gui content is built from parsing output by various tools such as the compiler; the output may have more detail on lines above/below

Comment: Thank you all guys for replying. I still haven't found the problem but instead have chosen another aproach to install my package. I used NuGetForUnity. If somehow someone is going through the same problem, here it is:

https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity/releases

Since it is not a visual studio tool, it doesn't require build/compile.